# Ubuntu 18.04 with linux-tools-5.3.0-40-generic and with linux-modules-5.3.0-42-generic not starting

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade, kernel

About one month ago, or even more time, I downloaded the latest ubuntu 18.04 upgrade (which installed kernel version 5.3.0-40). Since then when I tried to select Ubuntu from my GRUB menu, it wouldn't turn on at all. The screen just kept black and it didn't do anything. I need to turn it off with the power button. So I just select GRUB menu option "Advanced Ubuntu Options" and there I can choose another version of the kernel (5.0.0-37) which still works.

Recently (yesterday) I downloaded the new latest upgrades, and now I have noticed that it installed the 5.3.0-42 kernel version, and **it has the same problem**. So, I can only turn on my PC with Ubuntu going to Advanced Options in GRUB and choosing Ubuntu 18.04 with linux 5.0.0.-37 generics. Any other options (5.3.0-40 and 5.3.0-42) do not work.

I have tried to change the kernel version which is chosen when I select Ubuntu from the GRUB menu by changing the index on the boot options, but the only thing it does is to point out the option "Advanced Ubuntu Options" and when I press enter, it points out the 5.0.0-37 kernel version, so I don't have to press the arrow keys to go to those options.

I have tried, as well, deleting the kernel versions which are not working, but I just found how to delete the oldest kernel versions (which in my case is the only one working properly), So I've deleted the oldest versions from 5.0.0-37 and had to keep the latest.

Does anyone know how to solve this? I've searched it everywhere, but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Please show us `dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc`  and `df -h` Edit your question for this information.

Comment: I've just found an easier solution. I've deleted those newest versions and kept only the 5.0.0-37 option. I just used "sudo apt-get purge linux-image... linux-headers... linux-modules" from all the options that were corrupted. I only kept linux-image, linux-modules and linux-headers from 5.0.0-37.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. It seems that a lot of people is having troubles with newest kernel available for 18.04.4 LTS

Comment: Actually it is quite easy to delete the latest Kernel (or any), just write apt-get remove and the linux image you want to remove. But notice that the actual and serious problem is that the "latest stable kernel" for our version is not working.